# Обработка строк из файла с занесением результатов в базу данных

Tags: скрипт, база-данных, строки, php, mysql

**Здравтсвуйте, друзья!**

Есть очень не простая, на мой взгляд задача:

1. Имеется **[файл (.txt)](http://xn----0tbdffbl8g.xn--p1ai/data.txt)**
2. В файле строки
       они содержат однотипную информацию.
3. Типы данных упорядочены, т.е.
       следуют друг за другом в строке
4. В разных строках, некоторые типы
       данных иногда
       отсутствуют(пропущены), а в других
       строках есть, порядок следования
       этих данных соблюдается в каждой из
       строк.

**Задача:**
Необходимо сконструировать скрипт, который:
Расставит типы данных по колонкам и результаты будут занесены в базу данных MySql.

Comment: Поскольку жёсткой структуры у информации нет, попробуйте разобрать входящую информацию регулярными выражениями.

Comment: @cheh1, какие колонки есть в Вашей базе данных ?

Comment: @ReinRaus, колонки такие: |Район|Объект|Адрес|Площадь|Этажность|Материал|Описание|Цена|Описание2|Телефон|
... друзья, покажите пожалуйста, хотя бы примерно - как разобрать информацию регулярными выражениями?

Comment: @cheh1, слишком сложный тогда парсинг и неблагодарный, я пас. Могу подсказать книгу Фридла по регуляркам почитать.  
Могу помочь как выделить адрес целиком, описание, цена, телефон.

Comment: @cheh1, а данные до вас доходят именно в таком виде или они храняться как-то по другому? В том смысле, что может быть их можно подготовить для дальнейшей обработки более правильно?

Comment: @Deonis, данные приходят в таком виде, даже приходиться некоторые строки разделять (делать перенос строки), бывает, что они склеиваются по три или более в одну строку!

Comment: @ReinRaus, спасибо за книгу, посмотрел - буду читать в свободное время. 
Покажи пожалуйста, как выделить адрес целиком, описание, цена, телефон, чтобы я хоть немного представил как это будет дальше!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно познакомиться с функцией [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php). Если данные каждой строки разделены каким-то определенным символом, то надо еще познакомиться с функцией [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php). Для задачи, как описали её вы, этого должно быть достаточно.

А по поводу "оплаты за труд" - так это на фриланс, но не на этом форуме.

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать!

Comment: @cheh1, что ж тут пробовать? )

    // читаем файл
    $content = file_get_contents('file.txt');
    // разбиваем по строкам
    $rows = $explode("\r\n",$content);
    // если, к примеру, данные у вас разделены точкой с запятой,
    // то следующий шаг
    $data_arr = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($rows as $line){
     $data_arr[$i++] = explode(';',$line);
    }
    // В итоге, имеем двумерный массив со всеми данными
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data_arr);
    echo '</pre>';

Comment: Тут лучше регуляркой, данные не однородны

Comment: @ReinRaus, может быть, но у меня впечатление, что файл у ТС в стиле CSV или аналогичный ему с разделителями.

Comment: @deonis ТС в первом пункте дал ссылку на образец файла, я тоже не сразу заметил :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, да, действительно не обратил внимание. Да уж, глянул и всё оказалось гораздо печальней.

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовый бесплатный софт для таких вещей, чтобы не изобретать велосипеды. Сам часто гоняю данные из excel в mysql и обратно через dbForge studio и mysqlConnector